# Powerquery & Zabbix API - DataSource.Error (500) Internal Server Error when asking for much data

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, zabbix

I am using Powerquery to fetch the data from Zabbix using their API. **It works fine when I fetch the data for some days**, but as I increase the period and the amount of data surpasses the millions of rows I just get the error below after some time waiting, and the query doesn't return anything.

[image]

I am using Web.contents to get the data as follows:

[image]

I have added that timeout as you can see above but the error just happens much before 5 minutes have passed. How should I solve this? Are there ways to fetch large amounts of data in power query in parts, without being all at once? Or does this error happen because of connection parameters inherent to zabbix configs.?

My team changed all the possible parameters regarding server memory and nothing seemed to have worked. One thing to notice is that, although power query seems to face the same error (500) internal server error if I get data for a period of 3 days or 30 days, **for the first case it shows the error much faster while in the last case it takes much more time and eventually gets to the same error.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a PHP memory limit hit, you should modify the maximum memory.

For example, in an Apache standard setup you should edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf` and modify the php_value `memory_limit` to a greater value (restart apache!).

The default is 128M, the "right" setting depends on the memory available on the system and the maximum data size you want to get.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: My team changed all the possible parameters regarding server memory and nothing seemed to have worked. One thing to notice is that, although power query seems to face the same error (500) internal server error if I get data for a period of 3 days or 30 days, for the first case it shows the error much faster while in the last case it takes much more time and eventually gets to the same error.

Comment: Did you check the apache logs? They will show the 500 error reason

Comment: I guess that the error occurs faster with few days because the history.get call requires less data from mysql. Asking for 30 days will require much more time to mysql to produce the result. Then, both 3 and 30 days calls are hitting the memory limit.

Comment: Yeah, it is actually solved now. It was due to nginx php parameters that were set very low. Thanks for the support